# Why is the connection string keyword 'server' isn't supported when updating database using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting to learn ASP.NET from the tutorials provided by Microsoft [Adding a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#scaffold-movie-pages). I followed all the steps in the MVC tutorial but when I try to update the database using the following command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I receive the following error:

```
Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
```

Here is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMovieContext-049fffd8-f933-434b-af70-f8ea13364efa;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Tried to follow the link provided in the error but couldn't solve the problem. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your connection string!!!

Comment: See if there is anything missing like : instead on ; or spelling mistake. If possible show the connectionstring without the sensitive information.

Comment: You need to use `Data Source` ("Use the Data Source keyword").

Comment: @MartinCostello where should i add it?

Comment: Seems your provider could be the SQLite which doesn't of course support the `server` parameter. Check out the `providerName` parameter of your connection string, it should be `System.Data.SqlClient` rather than `System.Data.SQLite`.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code&force_isolation=true#sql-logging-of-entity-framework-core  I has to match var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext");

Comment: @KarimElezabawy In your connection string instead of `server`.

Comment: @phuzi , i have provide the connection string